# The sum of finite exponential series with a quadratic phase

Tags: summation, roots-of-unity, exponential-sum

How can I prove that:
$$
\sqrt \frac K2 + i \sqrt \frac K2=\sum^K_{m=1}\exp\left(i\frac \pi Km^2\right)
$$
When $K$ is even.

Comment: Do you know the residue theorem? Super roughly: If so, you can construct a function whose poles include the first $K$ integers and whose residue at each of the poles is the corresponding summand. Then you can get the left hand side by integrating over a rectangular contour around those integers.

Comment: Related but not quite [Gauss' sums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_sum).